# Using Custom Activity from another Interop

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

### Short Version

I want to use an activity in another activity, the only solution that I find is to use `Interop Activity`. But now i got some problem with the Workflow Fundation 4.5 Interop.

### Long Version

My project is in C# .NET 4.5. 
My first activity do a simple addition between two doubles. I did this one with the xaml designer tools.
My second activity is just calling the first activity with the Interop Activity.

Here my ViewModel: MyMain.cs:

```
public class MyMain : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    public double A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            if (a == value) return;
            a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }

    public double B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            if (b == value) return;
            b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }


    public double G
    {
        get { return g; }
        set
        {
            if (g == value) return;
            g = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("G");
        }
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Activity act = testing();
        Dictionary<string, object> ins = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        ins.Add("A", A);
        ins.Add("B", B);
        var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(act, ins);
        MessageBox.Show(output["G"].ToString());

    }
    public DynamicActivity testing()
    {

        A = 5.3;
        B = 2.1;


        // Define the Input and Output arguments that the DynamicActivity binds to
        var aa = new InArgument<double>(A);
        var bb = new InArgument<double>(B);
        var gg = new OutArgument<double>();
        return new DynamicActivity()
        {
            Properties = 
            {
                new DynamicActivityProperty() {Name = "AA", Type = typeof (InArgument<double>), Value = aa},
                new DynamicActivityProperty() {Name = "BB", Type = typeof (InArgument<double>), Value = bb},

                new DynamicActivityProperty() {Name = "GG", Type = typeof (OutArgument<double>), Value = gg}
            },
            Implementation = () =>
                new Sequence
                {
                  Activities =
                  {
                      new Interop()
                      {
                          ActivityType = typeof(Adds),
                          ActivityProperties =
                          {
                              {"A", new InArgument<double>(env => aa.Get(env))},
                              {"B", new InArgument<double>(env => bb.Get(env))},
                              {"C", new OutArgument<double>(env => gg.Get(env))}
                          }
                      }
                  }
                }
        };
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(propName);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My xaml: MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ActWpf.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Resultat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="34,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="367,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Click="Calculate"/>
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="160,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I got that warning which I find nothing to fix it:

```
System.Activities.Statements.Interop is obsolete: The WF3 Types are deprecated. Instead, please use the new WF4 Types from System.Activities.*
```

My execution error(I translate the error because normally it's in french):

```
DynamicActivity': The private implementation of the activity
'1: DynamicActivity' gives the follow validation error : Invalid value specify for the property 'ActivityType' of the Interop Activity 'Interop'.
 The value of this property have to be System.Type which herite ofSystem.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.
```

here the french, if that can help:

```
'DynamicActivity': L'implémentation privée de l'activité '1: DynamicActivity' présente l'erreur de validation suivante :   Valeur incorrecte spécifiée pour la propriété 'ActivityType' de l'activité Interop 'Interop'.
```

La valeur de cette propriété doit être un System.Type qui hérite de System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem.
Normally, if your activity work well you can find them in a specify div in the `xaml workflow` in `Toolbox`.
A specify div will be add foreach of your projects/namespaces and you can find and drag/drop your activities from those namespaces.